# Number comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is "11500" < "7000" as strings true?

Or am I the only one getting true when evaluated in chrome console

I know to get correct answer I can just use +"11500" < +"7000".

I just want to know why isn't it getting parsed like "5" < "2" is false the string get's parsed but not "11500" < "7000"

does it have to do with binary?

Comment: Strings are parsed as letter-by-letter whereas a number is not represented through Unicode but rather has an actual binary value that can be used in arithmatic and logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"11" < "2" = true, Because character '1' in ASCII table is 49 and character 2 in the ASCII table is 50, so In above example, The first letters will be compared, If it was equals, the next letters will be compared to each other and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Because strings are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) in JavaScript, and `"1"` is less than `"7"` (as characters).

`+` operator converts strings to numbers, which are then compared as expected.

Comment: For reference, the character codes are `49` and `55`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared character by character with respect to their charcodes

Here because "11500" has characters greater than  "7000"

1(49 as charcode) less than  7(55 as charcode) = true so goes the series

You can see charcodes for 1 and 7 as below

```
   "1".charCodeAt() //49 
   "7".charCodeAt() //55
```

Comment: Actually, because '1' has a lower character code than '7'. (49<55)

Comment: So you're saying that `5 < 4` is true?

Comment: 4  is 52,5  is 53 so no @HunterMcMillen

Comment: Doesn't really count when you edit our your initial answer, then reply to me based on your current one.

Comment: yes i didnt said about charcodes at that time so you are right